# Any ways to remove a corruped x-wav file?

Tags: file, ogg

So, i decided to download Terraria's Dungeon Spirit death sound for a GD texture pack, i was dumb enough to use windows renaming feature to change the file extension from .x-wav to .ogg. Now the file is corrupted, when i try to rename it or the folder its residing in, Windows Explorer crashes. When i try to delete it, the deletion message pops up but never gets anywhere.

Ive tried sfc /scannow, nothing found. Windows Defender scanning, antimalware service executable makes my cpu a frying pan and Windows Defender lags out when it gets to the file. Deleting i mentioned earlier. Renaming (includes back to its original format) i also mentioned earlier. Shredding the file crashes the shredder. Situation is looking pretty  hopeless.

Comment: Just renaming a file should not cause anything like that. Based on these symptoms it sounds like your HDD might be on the way out...

Comment: no idea, i can still interact with other files just fine and i have quite a lot of storage left

Comment: Well, try to delete it through the command prompt?

Comment: tried that, waited like 2 minutes and nothing

Comment: if obs works with file explorer i can try and get a recording of it

Comment: welp sadly it doesnt